# .Net entity framework Ignore constraints based on ConnectionString

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, connection-string

I have a `DBContext` in code first approach. It will accept the connection string as a parameter.

Can I Ignore the foreign key constraints based on the connection string provided by User?

```
public class EFDbContext : DbContext{
     public EFDbContext(string connection="Default"):base(connection)
     {
     }
     public DbSet<Contact> Contact { get; set; }
}
```

My `Contact` class look like this:

```
public class Contact
{     
    [Key]
    public long ContactId { get; set; }


    //Foreign key to Contact
    [ForeignKey("SystemUsers")] //**Need to ignore this constaint If DB is NoRelationsDB**
    public Guid UserId { get; set; }
    public virtual SystemUsers SystemUsers { get; set; }
}
```

My usage of the entity is:

```
 EFDbContext context=new EFDbContext();
 EFDbContext context1=new EFDbContext("NoRelationsDB"); //If the connection string is this then we have to ignore all the constraints in Tables.
```

Comment: if you want to ignore the constraints, what's the point of having them? Constraints are there for a reason. What's the reason you want to ignore them sometimes? It smells like a design flaw somehow.

Answer (score 2):

> Can I Ignore the foreign key constraints based on the connection string provided by User?

No. Foreign Key Constraints are part of the schema design in the database.  The constraints will be enforced (or not) for all users.

In SQL Server there are a couple of scenarios where constraints are ignored.  If you mark a constraint as NOT FOR REPLICATION then the replication agents are allowed to bypass the constraints.  And if you are loading data using a bulk API you can optionally skip constraint checking.

Other than that you can disable all constraints, load data, and then re-enable them.  Or you can use triggers to enforce the referential integrity, and code the trigger to skip the checks on some condition.

Comment: User is using different connection strings with a code first approach. If connection string point to different physical databases then why would you say no? Read his question `If DB is NoRelationsDB`...

Comment: Two different instances of the same DbContext type in a single AppDomain cannot have a different model.  OnModelCreating() will only run the first time an instance of the DbContext type is created.  And the model has no effect on the FK constraints in an existing database.

Comment: Ok you are right, if you edit your answer I can remove my down vote.